# WindowsIdentity always returns IIS user

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-authentication

I have an asp.net web application, on which i try to implement Windows authentication.

The application is hosted on IIS, and runs under Administrator account.

In the application, i am trying to get the name of the current windows logged-in user, ex Catalin Gavan.

Whatever i try, i always get the administrator user, the one which runs the ApplicationPool.

Here is what i tried:

```
Request.LogonUserIdentity);    // "NT AUTHORITY\\IUSR"
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();    // "ADIDEVNET\\administrator"
WindowsIdentity.GetAnonymous();    
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(true);    // null
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(false);    // "ADIDEVNET\\administrator"
```

How can i get the current logged-in windows user, from code behind?

[image: AppPool settings]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turn on Windows Authentication and that should fix it. Secondly, when you set the identity to administrator in the Advanced Settings, it will always log in as the administrator. Remove the identity from there, as well. A user will "impersonate" the admin account when that is set.

Try these web.config settings.

```
<system.web>
...
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" /> <!-- may want to remove this if you want to allow anonymous -->
</authorization>
<identity impersonate="false" />
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET Web Forms, you should access `Page.User`, and in ASP.NET MVC or Web API, you should call `Controller.User` or `ApiController.User` accordingly. This user identity comes from the request and is set as the thread identity.

`WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent` returns the process identity, which is obviously the application pool identity you set.